# Arduino pull-up resistor not working

Tags: arduino-uno, electronics, pull-up

I made a circuit where when I press a button, a LED lights up using a pull-down resistor. But when I tried the same with a pull-up resistor instead, the LED remains off (whereas I expected it to be on by default and go off when I push the button). What is the problem?

Here is the circuit:

[image]

And here the code:

```
int BUTTON = 7;
int LED = 8;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(BUTTON, INPUT);
  pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  digitalWrite(LED, digitalRead(BUTTON));
}
```

Comment: Is that LED the right way around? The cathode side or the more negative side is the one with the cut-off edge, and while it's really hard to see from those kinds of drawings, if _looks_ like anode is drawn towards the ground there, so the wrong way around.

Comment: Try connecting the button to 5V, you have no signal transition. With a pull up the switch has to ground it. With a pull down the switch needs to drive it high.

Comment: @ilkkachu yes, I just displayed it incorrectly in the picture.

Comment: @Gil but the button is connected to 5V via the 10K resistor. As is shown in circuit diagrams online.

Comment: It is important where the other end of the resistor is connected.  If you want pull up connect it to Positive the switch to negative, if you want pulldown connect it to ground and the switch to positive.  Try this link it will help you understand: https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/

Comment: @Gil but isn't that exactly what I did in the schematic? Resistor is connected to positive and the switch to negative. And the MCU between the resistor and the switch like in the [circuit diagrams here](https://eepower.com/resistor-guide/resistor-applications/pull-up-resistor-pull-down-resistor/).
Btw thanks for the link! Looks like a great resource.

Comment: The drawing looks good, except for the LED. The code looks also good. So, show us the picture of your real circuit on breadboard. There may be a chance that your breadboard's broken.